# 3.1 Auth working example of login/logout controller methods?

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-auth

Does anyone happen to have a working example of Auth in 3.1? I've been trying to get this to work, but have not had any luck.

New to Kohana, first attempt is 3.1. Found Bonafide, but don't need it since I'm starting w/ 3.1.

Been using examples from kerkness.ca's wiki, but they're for 3.0, and I'm too new to Kohana to know what to do. Would love to see a working example, hopefully to get buy-in from the rest of my dev team.

Answer (score 9):

I have created a quick tutorial that shows how to use the Kohana 3.1 Auth module using the ORM driver.  It covers the steps necessary to implement creating users, logging in and out, and viewing logged in user info.  Hopefully it is a good starting point.

Link to tutorial: [Auth module for Kohana 3.1 using ORM Driver](http://jdstraughan.com/post/auth-module-for-kohana-31-using-orm-driver)

Comment: This was very helpful. For Kohana 3.3 you need to change Request::current()->redirect() to HTTP::redirect(). I'm not very experienced with Kohana so I don't know if there's a newer implementation of the current() method with HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the problem was, but after my third from-scratch attempt, I was able to get it to work. I used this:
http://github.com/biakaveron/kohana-auth/wiki